# SQL statements of package not available in db2 catalog table

Tags: db2

I want to check SQL statements of DB2 packages. But there are no statements available in DB2 catalog tables.

I used the query :

```
SELECT STMT FROM SYSIBM.SYSPACKSTMT
WHERE NAME =<package-name>
```

But there are no statements in `STMT column`. Can anyone please suggest where else can i check sql statements of a package?

FYI, I am using `DB2 Z/OS V10`. We are going to migrate to `V11` but before that want to make sure that packages which are referincing to `SYSSTR system tablespace` are modified as part of pre-migration to `v11`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i can help you there. We are also on DB2 Z/OS V10 and i found a table called

```
SYSIBM.SYSPACKSTMT
```

In the table there is a COLUMN called STMT which is empty too but also a column called STATEMENT and it contains the SQL Statements.
So have a look into that table

```
SELECT STMNT_ID, STATEMENT FROM SYSIBM.SYSPACKSTMT 
WHERE NAME = <package name>
```

Edit: 
Ok you say there is no column STATEMENT in the table SYSPACKSTMT:
Well here are all columns this Table has on our Z/OS DB2 V10.
I can't exclude that your table is different but i doubt that as its an System table of DB2

- LOCATION
- COLLID
- NAME
- CONTOKEN
- SEQNO
- STMTNO
- SECTNO
- BINDERROR
- IBMREQD
- VERSION
- **STMT**
- ISOLATION
- STATUS
- ACCESSPATH
- STMTNOI
- SECTNOI
- EXPLAINABLE
- QUERYNO
- ROWID
- STMT_ID
- **STATEMENT**
- STMTBLOB

If your SYSPACKSTMT table contains different columns then i am afraid i can't help you. On my companies DB2 it looks like that and the STATEMENT column contains the SQLs. If it does look different i suggest talking to your db admins.

Edit2: The link to the official db2 documentation by IBM. It also lists the STATEMENT Column wih the description:

> The complete text for the SQL statement that the row represents.

So exactly what you are looking for!
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsyspackstmttable.dita?cp=SSEPEK_10.0.0%2F10-0-75

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, "there are no statements in STMT column". Can you suggest any other way to find statements?

Comment: Well i told you above that there is another table called SYSIBM.SYSPACKSTMT and that this one also has a column called STATEMENT where i find the SQL-Staments here. I even gave you an sql to use.

Comment: There is no column "STATEMENT" in SYSPACKSTMT, the column name is STMT. And as i said in my quetion. STMT doesn't have that statements. I need to know if there is any other place where i can check statement. I know we can see statements using CA platinum, but unfortunalty that option is not working for me due to some limitations.

Comment: I edited my answer and added proof that there is a column called STATEMENT in the SYSPACKSTMT table on my companies DB2 and also in the official documentation for this table provided in the IBM knowledgecenter.